# Set RadGrid rows height smaller than default value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, asp.net-4.0, radgrid

I'm trying to make the height of each row as small as possible, using this [Telerik post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-set-the-row-height-of-radgrid) as example. The issue is that if I set the height greater than the default (in the case of the example, 150px), it works fine. If it's below, then it does not work.

I also looked at the following [Telerik link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/543950-radgrid-row-height), which (I believe) is the same thing I'm doing here (set `CssClass` for `ItemStyle` and `AlternatingItemStyle`) but this worked for him.

Also, this radgrid is on a `masterpage`, but that shouldn't make a difference.

This is my radgrid markup:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridSets" runat="server" Width="100%" BorderColor="Silver" 
BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" onprerender="PreRender" >
<MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" CommandItemDisplay="Top" Font-Size="7" 
AllowAutomaticUpdates="true" >
    <ItemStyle CssClass="item-style" />
    <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="item-style" />
    <CommandItemSettings ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" ShowRefreshButton="false" />
        <Columns>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn datafield="carrier" headertext="sugbgroup"/>                        
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn datafield="count" headertext="count"/>                        
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

The CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .header, .cell
    {
        display:table-cell; 
        vertical-align:top; 
        padding-left:10px; padding-right: 10px; 
        font-size: 9pt;
        border: none;
        padding-top: 4px;
    }
    .even
    {
        background-color: #b2d3ec;
    }
    .odd
    {
        background-color: #d8e9f3;
    }
    .cell
    {
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px;
    }
    html .RadMenu .rmRootGroup {
        background-image: none;
    }

</style>
<style type="text/css">
    .RadGrid .item-style td
    {
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        height: 10px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody replied, I ended up using the `GridView` control.